# How can I create a docker file with payara mini?

Tags: docker, payara

Hello I need to create a docker file with payara mini in it,payara must listen on port 8080.Can you help me to create this docker file and run it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Payara have official images of their products on Docker Hub.

Perhaps you could use that images or, since they're an automated build from Github, you can take a look to theirs `Dockerfile` and build your own one.

**Payara Docker Hub**

https://hub.docker.com/u/payara

Comment: https://github.com/payara/docker-payaramicro/blob/master/Dockerfile i think this wil work for me,how can i run this docker file

Comment: You have instructions on Docker Hub. You only have to execute `docker run -p 8080:8080 payara/micro`. I suggest you to take a look to https://docs.docker.com/ to find a solution to this type of questions. Please, validate the answer if it was helpful for you.